# Как в PHPStorm 2021.1.3 отключить изменение вкладок при переключении веток git

Tags: phpstorm

По умолчанию набор вкладок для каждой ветки гита сохраняется свой. При переключении веток этот набор меняется. Как отключить эту функцию?

Comment: На 2021 не знаю, на современных IDEA-подобных IDE появляется всплывающее сообщение, в нем нужно нажать Configure, снять первую галку, нажать ОК.